# how to extract a metadata track from MP4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, vlc

I need to extract metadata track from a MP4 file and save as separate file. I see that, using ffmpeg I can extract standard tracks like Audio or Video or Subtitle track and save it as a new file. For ex: to save audio track I use the command below:

```
ffmpeg -i input-video.avi -vn -acodec copy output-audio.aac
```

But my need is to save a proprietary metadata track. Any pointers will be helpful.

Here is output of `ffmpeg` to know different traks that are present in the file. Particuarly, I am interested in extracting track corresponding to *Stream #0:3(eng)*...

```
C:\Users\rkumar\Documents\work\tools\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg.exe -i input.MP4
ffmpeg version N-57176-g64b3aaf Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Oct 15 2013 21:32:52 with gcc 4.8.1 (GCC)

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.MP4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp41
minor_version   : 538120216
compatible_brands: mp41
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:09
Duration: 00:00:10.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 834 kb/s

Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 
854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 679 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:09
handler_name    : AVC
timecode        : 00:00:13:22

Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:09
handler_name    : AAC
timecode        : 00:00:13:22

Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:09
handler_name    : TCD
timecode        : 00:00:13:22

Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (ssmd / 0x646D7067), 5 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:09
handler_name    : MET

Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 10 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:09
handler_name    : SOS
```

Comment: here is output of ffmpeg

Comment: ffmpeg output is long. so in put only relevent info from the output.
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709
), 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 679 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94
 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    :         AVC
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    :         AAC
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (ssmd / 0x646D7067), 5 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    :         MET

Comment: That's not the complete output. You should provide the complete output and add it to your question instead of trying to cram it into a comment.

Comment: I updted my original questin with ffmpeg output

Comment: Do you want to extract metadata or simply data on a given track? Using `ffprobe -i input` you could dump this in a file a then extract the metadata from it by parsing the output. That would my approach for extracting metadata with ffmpeg.

Comment: I actually want to extract the data present in the metadata track. If possible, an you please elaborate on how to use ffprobe to do this.

Comment: @ravi the metadata is stored in the "moov atom" within MP4 bytes. Just open your file in a hex editor and search for **moov** text, from its position go backwards by 4 bytes and read the integer value of those 4 bytes. That 4 byte number tells you total size of metadata bytes. Now you can copy from start-of-moov position up to that **total size - 4**. Hex editor will tell you how many bytes you have selected so keep going until enough then copy and paste into new hex document. Save that as file (eg: myMetadata.bin).

Comment: @ravi, a file is made of bytes so confirm what you mean by "save metadata as new file"? You want to extract metadata bytes (ignore audio & video bytes)? Or you want the metadata entries as text? Meaning with _stream 0:3_ you want the text "creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:09" etc without copy-pasting? Confirm otherwise no-one can answer your question...

Comment: I want to extract metadata bytes and save it to a new file. I want to ignore audio and video bytes. I hope it is clear now. If there are still any questions/doubts, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the meta data track with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input-video.avi -map 0:1 -c copy -copy_unknown -f data data.bin
```

This will save the meta data in `data.bin` which is a binary file so there will be some additional processing required to get the data out.